# Proving strong completeness of propositional logic by assuming weak completeness via algebraic methods.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, algebraic-logic

In ***logic via algebra*** (page $93$), Halmos tries to prove *strong* completeness ( if $S\models q$  then $S\vdash q$) assuming *weak* completeness ( if $q$ is a valid in the Boolean logic $(A,F)$ then $q\in F$ )

**Theorem**: For any proposition $q$ and any set $S$ of propositions in $(A,F)$, If $S\models q$ ,then $S\vdash q$.

His proof (bolding is mine ) :

> Suppose $S\models q$. Let $\hat S$ be the set of (provable) consequences of $S$. Then $\hat S$ is a filter that includes $F$. We must show that $q$ is in $\hat S$. **The assumption $S\models q$ implies that in the Boolean logic $(A,\hat S)$ the proposition $q$ is valid**. therefore $q$ is provable (in symbols, $\vdash q$) in $(A,\hat S)$ by the (weak) completeness theorem for $(A,s)$. In other words, $q\in \hat S$,as was to be shown

My question is: I don't see why this bolded sentence is true. Why is assuming that $S\models q$ implies that $q$ is valid in $(B,\hat S)$?

What I understand so far is that we have the Boolean logic $(A,F)$ and we have the filter $\hat S$ of all consequences from $(A,F)$. Now we define a new congruence relation induced by the filter $\hat S$ on $A$ to get the Boolean logic  $(A,\hat S)$ but I can not see how does this entail the implication mentioned above.

Any help?

Comment: This might be wrong, but isn't Halmos begging the question here? For $\hat S$ is the set of deductive (and not semantic) consequences of $S$. So, for $S⊨q$ to imply that $q$ is valid in the Boolean logic $(A,\hat S)$, we have to assume that all syntactic consequences of $S$ are semantic as well, which is strong completeness already.